# Show that a continuous function with a zero in between every zero is identically 0

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and for every $0\le a,b\le 1$, there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0.$ Show that $f$ is identically $0$.

Suppose there exists an $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)\ne0.$ Thus, by continuity, either there exists a $\delta_1$ such that if $x\in(x_0-\delta_1,x_0+\delta_1),$ then $f(x)>0$ or, similarly there is a $\delta_2$ such that if $x\in(x_0-\delta_2,x_0+\delta_2),$ then $f(x)<0.$ Im a bit stuck as to where to go from here. I want to contradict this by showing there must be a zero in one of these regions but I can't figure out how. Does anyone have any hints

Comment: Then choose $a = x_0 - \delta_1, b = x_0 + \delta_1$. Does there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ with $f(c) = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right! If there exist $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$, we can suposse that $f(x_0)>0$. Then we can take $\delta>0$ such that

1. For all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ we have that $f(x)>0$
2. $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subseteq (0,1)$

By hyphotesis, there exist $c\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ such that $f(c)=0$. This is a contradiction!

Comment: But how do you know that there is a zero in  $(_0−\delta,_0+\delta)$, couldn't it be in some point in $(0,1)$ but outside  $(_0−\delta,_0+\delta)$

Comment: @user604165 By assumption, for *every* $0\leq a<b\leq 1$ there is a $c$ *in* $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$. So in particular, this holds for $a=x_0-\delta$, $b=x_0+\delta$.